# Javascript - prevent nested events

Tags: javascript, html, events

I have the following structure in my HTML:

```
<tr id="151_movie" onclick="display_details(this);">
<td name="td_btn"><button id="151_btn_row_remove" name="btn_row_remove" type="button"></button></td>
<td>New Item just added</td>
<td>Blah</td>
<td>Blah</td>
<td>Blah</td>
<td>
<input type="text" id="151_file_video" name="meta_input" placeholder="Enter Filename" value="">
</td>
</tr>
```

I'm assigning event handles on my tr and btn_row_remove. Obviously the tds inside the tr will have the same event handler as the tr. I want my tds to NOT to have the same event handlers as the row, but the button (inside the td) to have it's own event.
I tried the following but this will disable the buttons event handlers ...

```
var td_btns = document.getElementsByName('td_btn');
    for (var i=0; i < td_btns.length; i++) {
      td_btns[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
            }, true);
    };
```

This is the event handler for the button inside the td:

```
var btns_row_remove = document.getElementsByName('btn_row_remove');    
for (var i=0; i < btns_row_remove.length; i++) {
          btns_row_remove[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(); //-> disables the row's event
            confirm_delete(this);
                }, true);
        };
```

How can I have events for parent (tr) and the grand child (button) elements but not for the middle child element (td)?

Comment: if(e.target.tagName==="TD"){return true;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt that passing false to addEventListener would solve the problem in my case:

```
var btns_row_remove = document.getElementsByName('btn_row_remove');    
for (var i=0; i < btns_row_remove.length; i++) {
          btns_row_remove[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation(); //-> disables the row's event
            confirm_delete(this);
                }, fasle); // -> disables event capturing ...
        };
```